# I’m getting a memory error “you need to load the kernel first” trying to boot Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, boot, dual-boot

I used to be able to boot Ubuntu from my SSD drive on a duel boot machine but now it says “you need to load the kernel first”.

I have tried to set the boot drive.
I found the partition with lost+found/ boot/ swapfile etc/ media/ var/ … and so on. I believe this is my partition for boot/grub/ by what I’ve read online.

My problem might be that there is nothing in this path.
[The Documentation says](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting#Search_.26_Set) /boot/grub should contain “ grub.cfg and many *.mod files. If looking for a specific file, include the name in the search to limit the number of returns”.
But there is nothing in this path but a file named grubenv.

Also, I don’t know what this disk is named. In grub it is (hd2,gpt4) and I can get the UUID number, but isn’t there another name that is something like /dev/hd1? Do I not need this to set the kernel if I ever find it?

I’m using Ubuntu 20.04
5.11.0-41 generic.

Answer (score 1):

The path may not be /boot/grub depending on how you installed things. Are you sure your using grub? Is your motherboard set to UEFI? (did you install using non-UEFI settings?) Have you tried the Ubuntu boot repair?

You never mentioned what version of Ubuntu is installed or how long it's been since you booted it. If this is an ancient Ubuntu 16.04 install then yeah perhaps grub. If it's something newer or current on an UEFI board perhaps not. The old way was /boot/grub on the root filesystem (docs are often very outdated) but these days the "path" you most likely need depending on how you answer my previous questions would be a separate partition mounted as /boot/efi

Dualbooting often sees Windows break the Linux boot setup but first thing to try is ye olde https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I’m using 5.11.0-41 generic

Comment: That's pretty old but also doesn't matter. Your kernel version isn't the issue ;) -unless you are giving that out as the Ubuntu version (it's the kernel version not the Ubuntu version)

Comment: I can only access the disk from grub. I can in no ways get to a terminal on the machine and do boot repair. Can I do boot repair from a USB somehow?

Comment: You've not answered any of my questions and sounds like you haven't read the boot-repair page either. You may want to do that if you want to get anywhere.

Comment: I changed from CSM to UEFI and I’m back in Ubuntu. Thank you. I guess it was a very easy fix but I didn’t know this was changed. I didn’t change it. Before I could toggle which OS to boot. Now I need to go change this in the BIOS each time, I guess.

Comment: Or change how things are set up i.e. convert Ubuntu to how Windows is forcing the boot mode. I was going to suggest switching the BIOS but you didn't give enough detail, but I did allude to it as a possibility. Best thing to do is set the BIOS to UEFI and just do a clean install of Ubuntu so it will change from grub. You could change things without the reinstall but I digress. Glad you're booting.

Comment: My motherboard has two places where UEFI can be changed. On the boot section and on a windows boot section under advanced options. Now I think it’s back to letting me toggle Ubuntu or Windows on the startup. I live and learn.

Comment: Yeah my workstation mobo has the same stupid thing. Two sections for the same thing one explicitly labeled as "for Windows" something that will never touch my machine.